# Ignore the processing errors in pandas data manipulations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to run a pandas merge on multiple files and trying to ignore the file not found error, but there is no output after running the code.

```
import pandas as pd
try:
    df_t = pd.read_csv('C:\\...\\aa_kk.CSV',dtype=str)
    df_u = pd.read_csv('C:\\....\\bb_jj.CSV',dtype=str)
    df_t_e = pd.DataFrame(df_t,columns=['CO','MD','PS','PE','PO'])
    df_u_e = pd.DataFrame(df_u,columns=['CO','MD','PS','PE','PO'])
    merge_tu = [df_t_e,df_u_e]
    result_tu = pd.concat(merge_tu)
    print(result_tu)
except Exception:
    print('not found')
```

I am expecting the data from `df_u` to be printed since there is no file exist for `df_t`. But, nothing is printed after the execution except the "not found".

Comment: *since no file exists for `df_t`* -> `df_t = pd.read_csv('C:\\...\\aa_kk.CSV',dtype=str)` throws an error and your code catches it by `except`.

Comment: It's bad practice to catch bare exceptions. If you are trying to catch a specific exception, use `except FileNotFoundError:`. This assures that your code will error out if another exception is raised. It's especially bad practice to wrap a long block of code with a bare except clause. Trust me, if you ever have to debug someone else's code where they do this, you will _know_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a list of files, create a list of DataFrames. When there's an error, it simply won't be added to the list. At the end, concat them together.

```py
files = ['C:\\...\\aa_kk.CSV', 'C:\\....\\bb_jj.CSV']
dfs = []
for file in files:
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(file, dtype=str, names=['CO','MD','PS','PE','PO'])
        dfs.append(df)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f'{file} not found')

df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not how we merge dataframes in python.

The correct way is using DataFrame.merge().
Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'df1name': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo'], 'value': [1, 2, 3, 5]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'df2name': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo'], 'value': [5, 6, 7, 8]})

df1.merge(df2, left_on='df1name', right_on='df2name')
```

BUT in your case, the `pd.read_csv` is inside the try and because the file not exists, an exception occurs and the message "not found" is printed.

Comment: It's more likely than not that the functionality they want is `concat`, and that they just used incorrect phrasing.

Comment: Yes... i figure..  anyway he has two funcionalities now lol